# Disable hover on specific ceils

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to avoid the hover on the 4 middle ceils in my table when the user make the hover on the entire line.

Initial state:
[image]

Hover state:
[image]

Expected result: Keep the 4 middle ceils in the initial state when hover.

HTML :

```
<tr class="gradeX odd" role="row">
   <td class="" tabindex="0"> CD-5-CZ-TOS-110.21 </td>
   <td class=""> OS6450-P24 </td>
   <td class="supportedClass"> Supported </td>
   <td class="supportedClass"> Supported </td>
   <td class="notSupportedClass"> Not supported </td>
   <td class="mediumClass"> Within 90 days of end of support </td>
   <td class=""> 2c:fa:a2:2e:15:c4 </td>
   <td class=""> T5184190 </td>
   <td class=""> 6.7.2.49.R01 </td>
</tr>
```

CSS (bootstrap)

```
.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover, .table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>td {
    background: #f3f4f6!important;
}

.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover, .table>tbody>tr.active>td, .table>tbody>tr.active>th, .table>tbody>tr>td.active, .table>tbody>tr>th.active, .table>tfoot>tr.active>td, .table>tfoot>tr.active>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td.active, .table>tfoot>tr>th.active, .table>thead>tr.active>td, .table>thead>tr.active>th, .table>thead>tr>td.active, .table>thead>tr>th.active {
    background-color: #eef1f5;
}
```

Comment: try using pointer-events: none;

Answer (score 0):

Define a new class for the middle td's maybe with the name "holdInitial" and in the css you can use the `::not(.holdInitial)` preprocessor on the querys where you define hover efects.

Answer (score 0):

Using class is not a good idea until you are not using loop, so I have made a solution that will select only first and last three element as you want.

```css
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td:nth-child(-n+5):not(:nth-child(n+2)), .table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td:nth-child(n+6) {
    background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Column</th>
   <th>Column</th>
   <th>Column</th>
   <th>Column</th>
   <th>Column</th>
   <th>Column</th>
   <th>Column</th>
   <th>Column</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td class="bg-danger">Column</td>
    <td class="bg-success">Column</td>
    <td class="bg-info">Column</td>
    <td class="bg-warning">Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td class="bg-danger">Column</td>
    <td class="bg-success">Column</td>
    <td class="bg-info">Column</td>
    <td class="bg-warning">Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td class="bg-danger">Column</td>
    <td class="bg-success">Column</td>
    <td class="bg-info">Column</td>
    <td class="bg-warning">Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```